# Is there a way to mimic map like access (using brackets) to get method on an arbitrary object

Tags: groovy

Is there a way in groovy where I can use brackets to access the get function like with maps? Something like this:

```
class Foo<V> {
    String bar = "Bar:"

    V get(Object lal) {
        return bar + lal
    }
}

def f = new Foo()
println(f["xxx"])
```

PS I would like to avoid extending the whole `Map` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works this way:

```
class Foo {
    String bar = "Bar:"

    def getAt(String lal) {
        return bar + lal
    }

    def getAt(int i) {
        return bar + i
    }
}

def f = new Foo()
println(f["xxx"])
println(f[0])
```

You need to pass concrete object class.